# Else part not running inside a while(next()) loop in jsp

Tags: jsp, if-statement, while-loop

I want to create a table to show if a class occupied or empty in a certain hour of day. The code executes the if part. But when the if condition is not satisfied, else part does not execute either.

```
            Date d = new Date();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(d);
                int dow = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String today = sdf.format(aja);

                        <td><%
                    String Hours = "07:00:00";
                    String sql1 = ("SELECT * FROM booked_classrooms WHERE block ='"+blockNo+"' AND room_no='"+roomNo+"' AND startTime='"+today+" "+Hours+"';");
                    boolean checkSql1 = false;

                    checkSql1 = st.execute(sql1);

                    if(!checkSql1){%>No Class<% }

                    else{
                        rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);

                    while(rs.next()){
                    Date classStart = sdf1.parse(rs.getString(6));
                      Date routineStartHour = sdf1.parse(today+" "+Hours);


                      c.setTime(classStart);
                    int dow1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                       if(dow1 == dow){
                    %>
                    <%=rs.getString(3)%> by <%=rs.getString(2) %><%

                       }else{ %>No Class<%
                       } } 
                     } %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning up the indenting, I can see the issue is that you were thinking the `else` on the `if` inside the loop would take care of the case where you never even enter the loop, which it won't. See below for one way to handle that case.

Also, you can get rid of `checkSql1 = st.execute(sql1);` which is wasting processing time. There's no need to run the query twice to see if it will run.

```
<td><%
String Hours = "07:00:00";
String sql1 = ("SELECT * FROM ....");
String noClassMessage = "No Class"; //making this a variable since its going to be used a few times
boolean blnEnteredLoop = false; //adding boolean to check if we ever enter the loop or not

rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);
while(rs.next())
{
    blnEnteredLoop = true; //setting to true because we're in the loop
    Date classStart = sdf1.parse(rs.getString(6));
    Date routineStartHour = sdf1.parse(today+" "+Hours);
    c.setTime(classStart);
    int dow1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if(dow1 == dow)
    {
        out.print(rs.getString(3)+" by "+rs.getString(2));
    }
    else
    {
        out.print(noClassMessage);
    } 
} 

if(!blnEnteredLoop)
{
    //if we never entered the loop, then print the message
    out.print(noClassMessage);
}
%></td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Now want to run this code 7 times each time adding an hour to the time... i used for loop but dint worked.Can you help. Thanks again